# Records updated during the day

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

```
SELECT `Item`.`name`, DATE_SUB(Item.modified, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
CASE
  WHEN DATE_SUB(Item.modified, INTERVAL 1 DAY) > Item.modified
  THEN 'FALSE'
  ELSE 'TRUE'
END status, `Item`.`restaurant_id` FROM `fs_development`.`items` AS `Item`
WHERE `Item`.`restaurant_id` = (677)
ORDER BY `modified` DESC LIMIT 1
```

I want to have a status field that have either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' to indicate if a record was updated within the day.

So far the above has not been working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `Item`.`name`, 
        DATE_SUB(Item.modified, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
        CASE WHEN date(Item.modified) = curdate()
             THEN 'TRUE'
             ELSE 'FALSE'
        END status, 
       `Item`.`restaurant_id` 
FROM `fs_development`.`items` AS `Item`
WHERE `Item`.`restaurant_id` = (677)
ORDER BY `modified` DESC
LIMIT 1
```